# Como mostrar detalhes de um item de reciclagem por id?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

No meu adaptador eu faço putExtra do id e depois nos detalhes da atividade eu quero pegar o id e através do id ir buscar no banco de dados as informações. por exemplo nome

> MyRecyclerAdapter

```
    holder.detalhes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent i = new Intent(context, DetalhesPonto.class);
            i.putExtra("id_detalhe", ponto1.getId());
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

        });
    }
```

> Método da base de dados

```
 public List<PontoDeInteresse> getPontoDeInteresseDetalhes(long id) {

    List<PontoDeInteresse> data1 = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db1 = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c1 = db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME_PONTO + " WHERE " + FIRST_COLUMN_PONTO + "= ?", new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
    StringBuffer stringBuffer1 = new StringBuffer();
    PontoDeInteresse ponto1 = null;
    while (c1.moveToNext()) {
        ponto1 = new PontoDeInteresse();
        //int id = c1.getInt(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id_ponto"));
        String name = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nome"));
        String desc = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("descricao"));
        String city = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id_cidade"));
        String latitude = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("latitude"));
        String longitude = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("longitude"));
        String rat = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("rating"));
        String cate = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndexOrThrow("id_categoria"));
        //ponto1.setId(id);
        ponto1.setNome(name);
        ponto1.setDescricao(desc);
        ponto1.setCidade(city);
        ponto1.setLatitude(latitude);
        ponto1.setLongitude(longitude);
        ponto1.setRating(rat);
        ponto1.setCategoria(cate);
        stringBuffer1.append(ponto1);
        // stringBuffer.append(dataModel);
        data1.add(ponto1);
    } return data1;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na nova Activity no caso a DetalhesPonto.class

Adiciona

O Comando:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int id_detalhe = intent.getStringExtra("id_detalhe");
```

Daí é só usar o id_detalhe na consulta.